# Pushing ByteArray to POST

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, http

I have a ByteArray of a sound recording.
I would like to make a POST request that sends this as a file.

Can I do this without having the user save the file because I can only see FileReference.upload as a way to send files to POST and I don't know how to make a FileReference from a ByteArray. Thanks.

Brendan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, use URLLoader and set it's format to [binary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html#!flash/net/URLLoaderDataFormat.html#BINARY), then you can put the bytearray into data property of request object.